# How to display contents of an Array using JavaFX GUI

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I have an array containing potential moves for a board game in one file. The display panel that informs the players of current state of game is in another file. I am trying to display this potential moves array as a menu (or table/combo box) in the display panel but I am having problems accessing the array because both codes are in separate files. Any thoughts on how I could display the contents would be greatly appreciated. The array is in my Main.java which contains loads of code but I will post the display panel code here. The array is in a function that returns nothing and prints to the console okay. I hope I have been able to articulate my problem, apologies in advance. calculatemoves function is in Main.java while displayLabels function is in Displaypanel.java

I have tried to create an object of Main but it is not possible because it extends Application(using JavaFX).

```
public void calculateMoves(int dice1, int dice2){
    String[] potentialMoves = new String[500];
    int k=0;        
    ....

    System.out.println("reach");
    System.out.println("k: "+k);
    for(k=k-1; k>=0; k--){
        System.out.println(potentialMoves[k]);
    }
    ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
    choiceBox.getItems().addAll(potentialMoves);
}

public void displayLabels(){
    if(gridSize < 31) {
        int numOfLabels = gridSize;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = numOfLabels; i > numOfLabels - 31; i--) {
            GridPane.setConstraints(labels[i - 1], 0, j);
            grid.getChildren().addAll(labels[i - 1]);
            j++;
            if (i - 1 == 0) break;
        }
 }
```

13-7 8-3 13-7 7-2 24-18 8-3 24-18 13-8 24-18 18-13 should be printed as a menu. This is the sort of result I get on my console at the moment.

Comment: I think that code ([mcve] ) would have been clearer and shorter than the attempt to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ComboBox. Porbably its really simple way.

```
class YourController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<String> cccombo;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ArrayList<String> yourArray = new ArrayList<>();
        //fill your array
        cccombo.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(yourArray));
    }
}
```